# Book about an impostor knight

Tags: story-identification, books

I've been having these thoughts lately that I'd read a book where one of the characters (a lowborn) pretended to be a knight so that they could compete in the tournaments. This character would win almost every tournament, and was highly feared. I don't know how reliable my memory is about this, but I think he was a frog, or became a frog, or had armor that looked like a frog, or something to do with frogs. No one knows his true identity, save maybe a cousin or sister, I can't remember. I truly wish I'd had more information, but this is all I've got to go on. If I'm right, I read this book in the last 3 years. Sadly, this is the only memorable thing about it. But I can't get it out of my head.

**EDIT**

Now that I'm thinking about it, the knight also yelled at other knights. Don't remember why, but he didn't reveal himself during this. Just yelled at them for something.

Comment: Except for the bits about frogs, this sounds a lot like the plot of the movie _A Knight's Tale_.

Comment: I can assure you it's not the movie. I adore the hell out of that movie, and while reading the book thought about the movie as well.

Comment: I believe you, which is why I didn't make that a formal answer. :-) I just can't think of anything else I know of that matches the description.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you read the "A Song of Ice and Fire" series? Parts of this sound very similar to the [Knight of the Laughing Tree](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Knight_of_the_Laughing_Tree) story. A mysterious knight shows up at a tournament and defeats three knights whose squires were bullying a smaller man. No one discovered the knight's identity, but he was rumored to be a crannongman, who were called "frog-eaters."

Additionally:

> When the defeated trio sought to ransom back their former property, the Knight declared his terms. That they ought to teach their squires honor. His voice sounded "booming" through his helm.

Comment: HAHAHA, that's it! OMG. I read the books. I knew there was something about a frog! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Could be Gene Wolfe's *The Knight*

https://www.worldswithoutend.com/novel.asp?ID=817